# Repeated Access Statement "Visited on" in biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

While trying the different biblatex referencing styles in texlive 2012, I came upon what I think might be a bug in biblatex-chicago. The access phrase "Visited on" was repeated. Has anyone had the same experience?

Here is the code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate,backend=bibtex,]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{fat,
author = {},
title = {Fat Secret},
date = {2012},
urldate = {2012-02-24},
url = {http://www.fatsecret.com/Diary.aspx?pa=fjrd&rid=2647991}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Sorry but I can't post pictures yet according to moderator. :)

Comment: You can add the picture with the button; just remove the `!` in front of the first `[` bracket: a user with enough privileges will reinstate it. I can confirm the "double" "visited on" and also that the output is different if one uses TeX Live 2011 or 2012; with TeX Live 2010 it's correct (and different from the other two).

Comment: I get the same thing. The problem seems to be that a call to `\printurldate` is adding the "visited", but a fieldformat (`urldate`) is doing it too. Whether it's related to the recent updating of biblatex, I couldn't say. Anyway, it does look like a bug, and would best be reported as such to David Fussner, since it may affect other things too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment the bibliography driver `online` prints the string `\urlseen` twice. The error occurs by the following line:

```
\printtext[urldate]{\printurldate}
```

which is used very often. `biblatex` v1.6 or newer uses a special field formatting for `printdate` and `printurldate`. That means `\pinttext[urldate]` and `\printurldate` are printing the string `urlseen`. So the easiest way to fix this issue is clearing definition. This can be done with the help of the package `xpatch`.

I think PLK will fix this in the next release:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{online}{urldate}{}{}{}
```

Here the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate,backend=bibtex,]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{fat,
author = {},
title = {Fat Secret},
date = {2012},
urldate = {2012-02-24},
url = {http://www.fatsecret.com/Diary.aspx?pa=fjrd&rid=2647991}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{online}{urldate}{}{}{}
\nocite{*}
\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If you want to change the file `chicago-authordate.bbx` you can simple replace

```
\printtext[urldate]{\printurldate}
```

by

```
\printurldate
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. At this point I have completely given up trying to understand the source files for the packages. I noticed that the syntax in those files appear like they were written in TeX so I am trying to learn it but it seems it will not be an easy task. Your answer is one less problem for me. Thanks!