# How to disable biblatex showing "visited on" on the references

Tags: biblatex

I'm writing a small article using luatex and Texstudio and biber:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[maxbibnames=3,style=chicago-authordate,backend=biber, url=false,doi=false, isbn=false]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\bibliography{}
\title{title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
First cite \parencite{Nichols2013}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Please copy the following code to a biblio.bib file.

```
@Article{Nichols2013,
  author       = {Nichols, Melanie and Townsend, Nick and Scarborough, Peter and Rayner, Mike},
  title        = {Trends in age-specific coronary heart disease mortality in the European Union over three decades: 1980–2009},
  journaltitle = {European Heart Journal},
  date         = {2013-10-14},
  volume       = {34},
  number       = {39},
  pages        = {3017--3027},
  issn         = {0195-668X},
  doi          = {10.1093/eurheartj/eht159},
  url          = {https://academic.oup.com/eurheartj/article/34/39/3017/506081},
  urldate      = {2017-11-07},
  abstract     = {{AimsRecent} decades have seen very large declines in coronary heart disease ({CHD}) mortality across most of Europe, partly due to declines in risk factors such as smoking. },
  file         = {Full Text PDF:C\:\\Users\\joe\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\ddxqcxys.default\\zotero\\storage\\TTNHMGPB\\Nichols et al. - 2013 - Trends in age-specific coronary heart disease mort.pdf:application/pdf;Snapshot:C\:\\Users\\joe\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\ddxqcxys.default\\zotero\\storage\\J4H4FEN4\\506081.html:text/html},
  shortjournal = {Eur Heart J},
  shorttitle   = {Trends in age-specific coronary heart disease mortality in the European Union over three decades},
}
```

When I compile the document I get this message "Visited on 11/07/2017 appears on the references even if I try to remove it.

[image]

There is a solution here
[Do not show the "(visited on <date>)" on the references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381506/do-not-show-the-visited-on-date-on-the-references)

```
url=false
```

But it doesn't work with my references and options.

There is a more complex solution:

[Repeated Access Statement "Visited on" in biblatex-chicago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64347/repeated-access-statement-visited-on-in-biblatex-chicago)

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{online}{urldate}{}{}{}
```

But it doesn't work either.

Strangely if I crate a simple reproducible example as :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber, url=false, doi=false, isbn=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Nichols2013,
    author       = {Nichols, Melanie and Townsend, Nick and Scarborough, Peter and Rayner, Mike},
    title        = {Trends in age-specific coronary heart disease mortality in the European Union over three decades: 1980–2009},
    journaltitle = {European Heart Journal},
    date         = {2013-10-14},
    volume       = {34},
    number       = {39},
    pages        = {3017--3027},
    issn         = {0195-668X},
    doi          = {10.1093/eurheartj/eht159},
    url          = {https://academic.oup.com/eurheartj/article/34/39/3017/506081},
    urldate      = {2017-11-07},
    abstract     = {{AimsRecent} decades have seen very .},
    file         = {Full Text PDF:C\:\\Users\\joe\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\ddxqcxys.default\\zotero\\storage\\TTNHMGPB\\Nichols et al. - 2013 - Trends in age-specific coronary heart disease mort.pdf:application/pdf;Snapshot:C\:\\Users\\joe\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\ddxqcxys.default\\zotero\\storage\\J4H4FEN4\\506081.html:text/html},
    shortjournal = {Eur Heart J},
    shorttitle   = {Trends in age-specific coronary heart disease mortality in the European Union over three decades},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    Test \parencite{Nichols2013}.
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I don't get the same problem. I just copied the content of that book there.

How can I solve this problem?
My real bibliography is much larger and I get many of these visited on .... messages and more information I don't want.

Comment: In case you'd like to contact the author about this problem, you can find contact information in the package documentation http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/biblatex-chicago/biblatex-chicago.pdf

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `chicago-authordate` style prints the "vistited on..." block whenever `urlyear` and `urlmonth` are not undefined. So you can prevent it by clearing both these fields.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[maxbibnames=2,style=chicago-authordate,backend=biber, url=false, doi=false, isbn=false]{biblatex}

\AtEveryBibitem{
    \clearfield{urlyear}
    \clearfield{urlmonth}
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{xiang_novel_2010,
title = {A Novel On-Chip Active Dispersive Delay Line ({DDL}) for Analog Signal Processing},
volume = {20},
issn = {1531-1309, 1558-1764},
url = {http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5570896/},
doi = {10.1109/LMWC.2010.2064761},
abstract = {In this letter, we report the first on-chip design of an active dispersive delay line ({DDL}) based upon the distributed amplification structure. This distributed amplifier {DDL} exhibits nanosecond delay variation in the frequency band from 11 to 15 {GHz}. An on-chip temporal imager is implemented with this active {DDL} and a linear chirp generator, realized by ramping the control voltage of a voltage controlled oscillator. The experimental data exhibits pulse stretching as well as pulse compression with this system.},
pages = {584--586},
number = {10},
journaltitle = {{IEEE} Microwave and Wireless Components Letters},
author = {Xiang, Bo and Kopa, Anthony and Apsel, Alyssa B.},
urldate = {2016-10-19},
date = {2010-10},
langid = {english},
file = {[3]A Novel On-Chip Active Dispersive Delay.pdf:/home/defrancaferr_joa/Documents/rtacft/documents/zotero/storage/IDFNSDX4/[3]A Novel On-Chip Active Dispersive Delay.pdf:application/pdf}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Test \cite{xiang_novel_2010}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh wow, you are quick.

Comment: @moewe I had a head start as the author asked me in a comment to another answer :)

Comment: I see, though I have to admit so had I: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/650

Answer (score 4):

### Update

`biblatex-chicago` has been fixed to suppress the `urldate` output in case `url=false,` is used to suppress the URL.

I can't say when exactly the fix was added, but things work fine with Version 2.1 (2021-03-27) [which also identifies itself as `2021/03/27 v 3.16`].

---

### Old answer

This is a style-specific issue with `biblatex-chicago`'s `authordate` style. That's why you can't reproduce it with `style=ieee`.

The style prints the URL access date even if the URL itself is suppressed.

You should probably notify the package author, in the meantime a fix is

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{bib+doi+url}{% 16th ed.
  \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldundef{urlyear}} or test {\iffieldundef{url}} or not togl {cms@url}}%
    {}%
    {\printurldate}% Date fix
  \iffieldundef{addendum}%
  {\newunit\newblock}%
  {\newcunit\newblock}%
  \iftoggle{cms@doionly}%
  {\iffieldundef{doi}%
    {}%
    {\printfield{doi}%
      \setunit*{\addperiod\addspace}\newblock%
      \clearfield{url}}}%
  {\ifboolexpr{%
      togl {cms@doi}%
      and
      not test {\iffieldundef{doi}}%
    }%
    {\printfield{doi}%
      \setunit*{\addperiod\addspace}\newblock}%
    {}}%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    togl {cms@eprint}%
    and
    not test {\iffieldundef{eprint}}%
  }%
  {\usebibmacro{eprint}%
    \setunit*{\addperiod\addspace}\newblock}%
  {}%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    togl {cms@url}%
    and
    not test {\iffieldundef{url}}%
  }%
  {\printfield{url}}%
  {}}%
\makeatother
```

Comment: +1 I totally agree that it is strange to print the url date if there is no url displayed.

Comment: I choose samcarter answer beause it's much easier and arrived earlier.

Comment: @moewe I see you have contributed to the package. Has this gone in, by any chance? And if so, could you update the answer to reflect that?

Comment: @FrederickNord I guess it was changed at some point yes. Thanks for the heads-up. Answer updated.